# PhpMyAdmin - config authentication refuses to work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't get config authentication to work in PHPMyAdmin on my local Win 7 PC with Apache 2.2 and MySQL 5.1. I've tried with two different versions of PHPMyAdmin, including the latest, 3.4.7.1. I've used the setup script, and checked my config.inc.php, which seems to contain the right values.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

But PHPMyAdmin refuses to take any notice and asks me for my password every time. This is driving me crazy!

Can anybody think why this might be happening and save me additional grey hairs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing. My initial problem was entirely due to my own idiocy. I didn't realise I needed to copy the config.inc.php out of /config into the root of phpmyadmin before it would take effect. Uh!

Once I did this I found I was able to get into PHPMyAdmin, but the UI was pretty much blank - no DBs were listed and not many options.

I finally got round this by (1) replacing all the contents of /phpmyadmin with a set of new files (2) saving config.sample.inc as config.inc, changing the 'auth' value to 'config' and adding lines for 'user' and 'password'. There must've been a config setting in my original file which was causing the blank UI issue.

If anyone else runs into similar probs, I'd suggest trying to copy config.sample.inc and modifying that instead of using the setup script.

In case it helps anybody, my successful config lines were

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Comment: On the contrary, your example was very helpful: I was doing the same mistake. I guess the documentation is a bit unclear ;)

Comment: Glad it helped somebody Alsciende!

Answer (score 0):

My `config.inc.php` in the root, had a space in its name and had me pulling my hairs for why `phpmyadmin` was ignoring any changes to it. And it wasn't quite apparent using the gui, but when I used `ll` in console I found I had somehow left a whitespace in the file name and removing that space solved the problem.

`config. inc.php` => `config.inc.php`

Answer (score -1):

What's the value of $i here?

You can also try to set:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'root';
```

BTW, is the password for `root` is really `root`? Isn't it just empty? If so, you will need to correct entries and add one more

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks FR, yes, the password for root was root.